# How can I outfit the Caves of Chaos to fit contextually with the Dragonlance setting?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-3.5e, dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures, dragonlance

I have been tasked with running *The Keep on the Borderlands* adventure module. Although it is normally set in Greyhawk, I’m interested in placing the adventure in a Dragonlance campaign setting, in the age of mortals.

As the characters will be starting in the City of Solace, without other advisement I plan to put the "Caves of Chaos" (location from the adventure module) in the Kharolis Mountains.

Reading through *The Keep on The Borderlands*, there are issues that make placing the *Caves of Chaos* into Krynn (the world of Dragonlance) non-trivial.

To give context, here is a quick plot summary of the module:

> The Realm of mankind is narrow and constricted. Always the forces of Chaos press upon its borders, seeking to enslave its populace, rape its riches, and steal its treasures... Bold adventurers from the Realm set off for the Borderlands to seek their fortune. It is these adventurers who, provided they survive the challenge, carry the battle to the enemy. Such adventurers meet the forces of Chaos In a testing ground where only the fittest will return to relate the tale.

Ostensibly the reason for finding and battling in the caves is for the adventurers to gain wealth and prestige. That's fine, however, the difficulty I'm having comes with outfitting the denizens of the cave.

You see the "Caves of Chaos" are a not one lair, but a  series of lairs with various creatures. The module mentions that the creatures ally and war with one-another.

> TRIBAL ALLIANCES AND WARFARE: ...there is constant fighting going on between the goblins and hob- goblins on one side and the orcs sometimes with gnoll allies, on the other - with the kobolds hoping to be forgotten by all, and the bugbears picking off any stragglers who happen by. With this knowledge, they might be able to set tribes to fighting one another, and then the adventurers can take advantage of the weakened state of the feuding humanoids.

In the Caves of Chaos, there is a Kobold Lair, Orc Lair, Goblin Lair, Hobgoblin lair, Ogre cave, Owlbear Den, Bugbear Lair (tending a slave pen), Minataur Cave (who is allied with the bugbears), Gnoll Lair, Hall of Skeletons.

What I am trying to do is outfit the caves with creatures that exist in Krynn, and have their alliances or warrings with one another be appropriate for the setting.

Notable; Orcs and Kobolds do not exist on Krynn, minotaurs do not necessarily ally with bugbears, maybe other issues.

It won’t be necessary to add stat blocks for monsters because I can look them up.

*(I put two edition tags because we’re using 5e rules, but for the setting using the published Dragonlance materials from 3.5 regarding Age of Mortals)*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110868/discussion-on-question-by-amethyst-wizard-how-can-i-outfit-the-caves-of-chaos-to).

Comment: Ok, having gotten a clearer idea of what you're asking, I'm failing to see how this isn't asking for idea-generation. I've removed the bounty (the rep should be returned to you and can be reapplied later), and closed the question. If you can find a way to give specific enough goals for what you're after that it'll work on the stack site, please do so. Otherwise, if you're more looking for a broad spread of unsortable suggestions, you're better off with a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/52137) or [chat].

Comment: I'll apologize for not getting to grips with this sooner, and it making all this mess, but let's try to work from here. I'll suggest maybe opening a question workshop on meta, because I think that'll be better tool for figuring this out than comments and iterations.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious choice for cave-dwelling creatures would be dwarves.

"Derro dwarves" live in total darkness and are "sometimes thought mad, and generally evil".

"Aghar dwarves" are "generally stupid" and "live in ruined cities and sewers".

Either group could plausibly be in a cave just because it's the place where they live.  Either group might be an antagonists for a group of player characters.

You might also consider goblins; kobolds are not in the Dragonlance setting but goblins are.

---

You've asked for ideas about "why adventures might want to kill them beyond them just being generally evil".

Normally this sort of plot hook is derived from the module you are running; unfortunately Keep On The Borderlands appears to be a "sandbox" type adventure, in which it's assumed that the player characters want to go fight monsters simply to have something to do.

In the absence of a real plot, I advise you to rely on the traditional motives:

- these monsters have treasure, and the player characters would like to take that treasure
- somewhere in this cave is a valuable magic item which the player characters need
- these monsters sometimes leave the cave and raid the nearby human settlement, and the player characters would like to kill them to stop them from doing that
- these monsters are occupying a cave network which the player characters would like to take for themselves
- the player characters would like to gain experience points and levels (usually phrased in-game as "improve their adventuring skills and make a name for themselves")
- some NPC has gotten lost in this area and the player characters need to rescue them by fighting these monsters
- some NPC has asked the player characters to fight these monsters as a favor, perhaps for one of the reasons described above

Comment: Is there a reason why you only cover goblins and dwarves? I imagine there are a large number of creatures that live in caves. ANd if Aghar dwarves usually live in cities and sewers...why  are they relevant for the cave?